# array conversion with in array PHP

Tags: php

i need to convert bellow `array` from

```
Array
(
[Property] => Array
        (
            [S] => Built As Condominium
        )
)
```

to

```
Array
(
[property] => Built As Condominium
)
```

is their any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an `implode` under a `foreach`

```
<?php
$arr=Array ( 'Property' => Array ( 'S' => 'Built As Condominium' ) );
foreach($arr as $k=>$arr1)
{
    $arr[$k]=implode('',$arr1);
}
print_r($arr);
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/135699)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the key of the array to implode the value in one line for example

```
$array['Property'] = $array['Property']['S'];
```

Results

```
Array ( [property] => Built As Condominium )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
  "Property" => array( 
    "S" => "Built As Condominium"
   )
);

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
  if($key == "Property") {
    $normalized_data['Property'] = is_array($value) && isset($value['S']) ? $value['S'] : NULL;
  }
}
```

**Program Output**

```
array(1) {
  ["property"]=>
  string(20) "Built As Condominium"
}
```

[Link](https://eval.in/135702)

Answer (score 0):

Implode is not necessary, or keys, just use a reference, i.e. the '&'. This is nice and simple.

```
$array = Array ( 'Property' => Array ( 'S' => 'Built As Condominium' ) );

foreach($array as &$value){
    $value=$value['S'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or.... if you don't know the key of the inner array but only care about its value (and assuming you want the first member of the inner array as your new value) then something like [reset](https://www.php.net/reset) inside a foreach loop would work:

```
$arr = array ('Property' => array( 'S' => 'Built As Condominium'));
$new = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $inner) {
    $new[$key] = reset($inner);
}
print_r($new);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [Property] => Built As Condominium
)
```